# Why is my video element logged like this?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, html5-video, video.js

This code is used in ExtJs5 to create a Video.js player.

I’m in trouble on a very simple problem (I think). I’m creating a custom HTML video in native JavaScript like the following:

```
console.log('id video ');
console.log(me.idVideo);

var video = document.createElement('video');
video.setAttribute('id', me.idVideo);

console.log('video');
console.log(video);

var sourceVideo = document.createElement('source');
sourceVideo.setAttribute('src', me.urlVideo);
sourceVideo.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4');
video.appendChild(sourceVideo);

var pNoJs = document.createElement('p');
sourceVideo.setAttribute('class', 'vjs-no-js');
pNoJs.innerHTML = 'Pour voir cette vidéo s\'il vous plait activez Javascript, ou mettez à jour votre navigateur pour qu\'il';
```

There is the output result:

```html
id video 
rc-player-formation-1437990801
video
<video id="rc-player-formation-1437990801_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" src="http://xxxxx.fr/OT_SENS/1437990801/video.mp4"><source src="http://xxxxx.fr//OT_SENS/1437990801/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" class="vjs-no-js"><p>Pour voir cette vidéo s'il vous plait activez Javascript, ou mettez à jour votre navigateur pour qu'il<a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supporte les videos HTML5</a></p></video>
```

I totally don’t understand video’s log, why are there all my attributes instead of my log just after the creation of the video?

Maybe ExtJs overwrote my id?

Comment: I don't see a problem?

Comment: Are you asking why `class="vjs-tech"` is on your video element?

Comment: Or are you asking why the child elements are in the logged video element? Because Firefox actually doesn’t do that: Firefox would only log the element itself without the closing tag. Anyway, please clarify what you want to know, what else you expected and how this is a problem at all.

Comment: i think he is asking: __video element is created empty, but when logging it, it shows all attributes that where added after console.log__ This is just reference, and console.log executes later than your code, so you see the result

Comment: By the way, just as an aside: _“Pour voir cette vidéo s'il vous plait activez Javascript”_, but if JavaScript is disabled, nobody will be able to read this message.

Comment: Thank of your anwsers. 
Why console.log is'nt executed just after the creation of the video?

And why the value of the video's id is'nt rc-player-formation-1437990801 but rc-player-formation-1437990801_html5_api.

This two points are strange